# Script para mudar jogador (jogo da velha Jquery)

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando fazer com que o jogo da velha mude o jogador que tem a vez, consegui fazer muda-lo do 'X' para o 'O', mas quando tento retornar para o 'X' e assim por diante, ele não vai.

Segue o código que fiz até aqui:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".botao").click(function() {
     $(this).text("X");
     $("#jogador").text("É a vez do jogador 2");

     mudarSimbolo();
   });

   function mudarSimbolo() {
     if ($("#jogador").text() == "É a vez do jogador 2") {
       $(".botao").click(function() {
         $(this).text("O");
         $("#jogador").text("É a vez do jogador 1");
       });
     } else if ($("#jogador").text() == "É a vez do jogador 1") {
       $(".botao").click(function() {
         $(this).text("X");
         $("#jogador").text("É a vez do jogador 2");
       });
     }
   }

 });
```

```css
.btn-default {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid red; width:320px; height:320px;">
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">3</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">4</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">5</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">6</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">7</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label id="jogador">É a vez do jogador 1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue o código com correção:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var player = 1;
  
   $(".botao").click(function() {
     if(player == 1) {
       $(this).text("X");
       player = 2;
     } else {
        $(this).text("O");
        player = 1;
     }
       
     
     $("#jogador").text("É a vez do jogador " + player);
   });

 });
```

```css
.btn-default {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid red; width:320px; height:320px;">
  
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">3</button>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">4</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">5</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">6</button>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">7</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">8</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default botao">9</button>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label id="jogador">É a vez do jogador 1</label>
</div>
```

O que fiz foi criar uma variável global no documento chamada `player`, ao clicar no botão, caso o `player` seja 1, então coloco X e atribuo 2 a essa variável para indicar que é o `player` 2 quem irá jogar, caso seja a vez do `player` 2 então faz o contrário, coloca O e a variável `player` passa a valer 1.

Comment: Chegamos a uma solução parecida :P se quiser removo a minha ;]

Comment: kk Mantenha a sua aí, está meio diferente, bom que da pra passar a mensagem que tem muitos jeitos de se fazer.

Answer (score 3):

Eu simplificaria a logica, basta criar uma variável global e verificar a mesma:

```js
var elem = "O";
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".botao").click(function() {
     $(this).text(elem);
     if (elem == "X") {
       elem = "O";
       $("#jogador").text("É a vez do jogador 1");
     } else if (elem == "O") {
       elem = "X";
       $("#jogador").text("É a vez do jogador 2");
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
.btn-default {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid red; width:320px; height:320px;">
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">3</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">4</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">5</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">6</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">7</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label id="jogador">É a vez do jogador 1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas(muitas) alterações.Implementei a verificação caso o botão seja pressionado novamente, não altere o valor definido. Testa ai e verifica o código para ver se entende.

```js
var vez = false;


$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".botao").click(function(event) {     
     //verifica se o botão já foi precionado e aborta.
     if ($(event.target).data("key") =="1"){
       return;
     }
     //verifica de quem é a vez
     if (vez) {   
         //indica a vez do jogador em questão
         $("#jogador").text("É a vez do jogador 1");
          $(event.target).html("X");
          //marca como botão já precionado.
          $(event.target).data("key","1");
          vez = !vez;
     } else {
         $("#jogador").text("É a vez do jogador 2");
         $(event.target).html("O");
          $(event.target).data("key","1");
        vez = !vez;
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
.btn-default {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid red; width:320px; height:320px;">
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">1</button><br>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">3</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">4</button><br>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">5</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">6</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default botao">7</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label id="jogador">É a vez do jogador 1</label>
</div>
```